# Why are my related tabs blank in Vtiger 6.0 when viewing an organisation?

Tags: vtiger

When viewing an Organisation in Vtiger 6.0 I have a list of "Related Tab" down the right hand side. Most of them are working correctly but the "Sales Order" and "Invoice" tabs are showing no results, even though the "Updates" pane on the "Organisation Summary" page shows "Sales order added" with the name of the sales order and a "days ago" field.

The "Sales Order" and "Invoice" related tabs both do some processing when I click on them and they both load the correct heading for their tables, however the tables are totally empty.

Is there anything I or another user might have done to inadvertently filter or limit the entries being displayed in the "Related Tab" section for Sales Orders and Invoices?

As part of troubleshooting this I have taken a copy of the database and installed it on a different subdomain with a brand new unzipped version of Vtiger 6.0 (with the security patch applied) however the issue still occurs in my testing environment, even after disabling all modules except for "Organisations", "Invoice" and "Sales Order". The production version of the site was previously upgraded from Vtiger 5.4 but the fresh install of Vtiger 6.0 files doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a fresh install with a fresh database and then had someone from the business do manual entry of the data they wanted to migrate. The business saw some value in doing a fresh start as a way to clean up their data.

Sorry I can't provide a more useful solution.